# Query on number field matching string fields

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-5

I have an ELK stack setup. When I am performing a query on number fields then it is also matching against string fields. For example, I am sending Load Balancer logs to ELK and if I perform `backend_processing_time:>5` on that then it is matching against `backend_processing_time` with value `0.001` too.

On kibana interface, it is showing that the query is matching string in the request message. I am not able to understand how a query against a number field is matching against a string.

In the dev tools section on kibana i tried to run the same query

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
           "range" : {
            "backend_processing_time" : {
                "gte" : 50000000000
            }
        } 
  }
}
```

Even with so much backend_processing_time i am getting results. I am not able to understand why this is happening.

I searched on other fields also which are of number type and found that all the queries done on number field are getting matched with string type fields.

I am providing a sample search result which i get for `backend_processing_time:>500000000` query. It can be seen in this result that backend_processing_time field is so small but still getting a hit.

```
{
  "_index": "logstash-2017.05.10",
  "_type": "prod-quizelb-logs",
  "_id": "AVvzYRgL49GPTZAKoDer",
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "backendport": 80,
    "received_bytes": 0,
    "request": "http://en.meaww.com:80/locales/en.json",
    "backend_response": 200,
    "verb": "GET",
    "message": "2017-05-10T17:19:52.881044Z Prod-ELB 172.68.144.71:34803 10.1.91.253:80 0.000075 0.000606 0.000019 200 200 0 1881 \"GET http://en.meaww.com:80/locales/en.json HTTP/1.1\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; SM-C900F Build/MMB29M; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/58.0.3029.83 Mobile Safari/537.36 [FB_IAB/FB4A;FBAV/122.0.0.17.71;]\" - -\n",
    "type": "prod-quizelb-logs",
    "clientport": 34803,
    "request_processing_time": 0.000075,
    "urihost": "en.meaww.com:80",
    "response_processing_time": 0.000019,
    "path": "/locales/en.json",
    "@timestamp": "2017-05-10T17:21:18.280Z",
    "port": "80",
    "response": 200,
    "bytes": 1881,
    "clientip": "172.68.144.71",
    "proto": "http",
    "@version": "1",
    "elb": "Prod-ELB",
    "httpversion": "1.1",
    "backendip": "10.1.91.253",
    "backend_processing_time": 0.000606,
    "timestamp": "2017-05-10T17:19:52.881044Z"
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      1494436878280
    ],
    "timestamp": [
      1494436792881
    ]
  },
  "highlight": {
    "backend_processing_time.keyword": [
      "@kibana-highlighted-field@6.06E-4@/kibana-highlighted-field@"
    ],
    "request": [
      "@kibana-highlighted-field@http@/kibana-highlighted-field@://@kibana-highlighted-field@en.meaww.com@/kibana-highlighted-field@:@kibana-highlighted-field@80@/kibana-highlighted-field@/@kibana-highlighted-field@locales@/kibana-highlighted-field@/@kibana-highlighted-field@en.json@/kibana-highlighted-field@"
    ],
    "elb.keyword": [
      "@kibana-highlighted-field@Prod-ELB@/kibana-highlighted-field@"
    ],
    "urihost.keyword": [
      "@kibana-highlighted-field@en.meaww.com:80@/kibana-highlighted-field@"
    ],
    "verb": [
      "@kibana-highlighted-field@GET@/kibana-highlighted-field@"
    ],
    "request.keyword": [
      "@kibana-highlighted-field@http://en.meaww.com:80/locales/en.json@/kibana-highlighted-field@"
    ],
    "type": [
      "@kibana-highlighted-field@prod@/kibana-highlighted-field@-@kibana-highlighted-field@quizelb@/kibana-highlighted-field@-@kibana-highlighted-field@logs@/kibana-highlighted-field@"
    ],
    "message": [
      "2017-05-10T17:19:@kibana-highlighted-field@52.881044Z@/kibana-highlighted-field@ @kibana-highlighted-field@Prod@/kibana-highlighted-field@-@kibana-highlighted-field@ELB@/kibana-highlighted-field@ 172.68.144.71:34803 10.1.91.253:@kibana-highlighted-field@80@/kibana-highlighted-field@ 0.000075 0.000606 0.000019 200 200 0 1881 \"@kibana-highlighted-field@GET@/kibana-highlighted-field@ @kibana-highlighted-field@http@/kibana-highlighted-field@://@kibana-highlighted-field@en.meaww.com@/kibana-highlighted-field@:@kibana-highlighted-field@80@/kibana-highlighted-field@/@kibana-highlighted-field@locales@/kibana-highlighted-field@/@kibana-highlighted-field@en.json@/kibana-highlighted-field@ @kibana-highlighted-field@HTTP@/kibana-highlighted-field@/1.1\" \"@kibana-highlighted-field@Mozilla@/kibana-highlighted-field@/5.0 (@kibana-highlighted-field@Linux@/kibana-highlighted-field@; @kibana-highlighted-field@Android@/kibana-highlighted-field@ @kibana-highlighted-field@6.0.1@/kibana-highlighted-field@; @kibana-highlighted-field@SM@/kibana-highlighted-field@-@kibana-highlighted-field@C900F@/kibana-highlighted-field@ @kibana-highlighted-field@Build@/kibana-highlighted-field@/@kibana-highlighted-field@MMB29M@/kibana-highlighted-field@; @kibana-highlighted-field@wv@/kibana-highlighted-field@) @kibana-highlighted-field@AppleWebKit@/kibana-highlighted-field@/@kibana-highlighted-field@537.36@/kibana-highlighted-field@ (@kibana-highlighted-field@KHTML@/kibana-highlighted-field@, @kibana-highlighted-field@like@/kibana-highlighted-field@ @kibana-highlighted-field@Gecko@/kibana-highlighted-field@) @kibana-highlighted-field@Version@/kibana-highlighted-field@/4.0 @kibana-highlighted-field@Chrome@/kibana-highlighted-field@/@kibana-highlighted-field@58.0.3029.83@/kibana-highlighted-field@ @kibana-highlighted-field@Mobile@/kibana-highlighted-field@ @kibana-highlighted-field@Safari@/kibana-highlighted-field@/@kibana-highlighted-field@537.36@/kibana-highlighted-field@ [@kibana-highlighted-field@FB_IAB@/kibana-highlighted-field@/@kibana-highlighted-field@FB4A@/kibana-highlighted-field@;@kibana-highlighted-field@FBAV@/kibana-highlighted-field@/122.0.0.17.71;]\" - -\n"
    ],
    "urihost": [
      "@kibana-highlighted-field@en.meaww.com@/kibana-highlighted-field@:@kibana-highlighted-field@80@/kibana-highlighted-field@"
    ],
    "path": [
      "/@kibana-highlighted-field@locales@/kibana-highlighted-field@/@kibana-highlighted-field@en.json@/kibana-highlighted-field@"
    ],
    "verb.keyword": [
      "@kibana-highlighted-field@GET@/kibana-highlighted-field@"
    ],
    "proto.keyword": [
      "@kibana-highlighted-field@http@/kibana-highlighted-field@"
    ],
    "port": [
      "@kibana-highlighted-field@80@/kibana-highlighted-field@"
    ],
    "type.keyword": [
      "@kibana-highlighted-field@prod-quizelb-logs@/kibana-highlighted-field@"
    ],
    "proto": [
      "@kibana-highlighted-field@http@/kibana-highlighted-field@"
    ],
    "elb": [
      "@kibana-highlighted-field@Prod@/kibana-highlighted-field@-@kibana-highlighted-field@ELB@/kibana-highlighted-field@"
    ],
    "backend_processing_time": [
      "@kibana-highlighted-field@6.06E@/kibana-highlighted-field@-4"
    ],
    "port.keyword": [
      "@kibana-highlighted-field@80@/kibana-highlighted-field@"
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1494436878280
  ]
}
```

**EDIT**

I got the mapping by running `GET /logstash-2017.05.11/_mapping/prod-quizelb-logs` query in kibana console.

The mapping which I am getting for `backend_processing_time` is showing this

```
  "backend_processing_time": {
    "type": "text",
    "norms": false,
    "fields": {
      "keyword": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
```

So it seems that this field is of text type thus causing this error to happen.

Now I have another confusion i.e. kibana is showing this as `number` but elasticsearch is showing this of type `text`. Also, this is getting mapped dynamically as i never created the mapping on my own. I think that they are getting created by logstash at the time grok filter is applied.

Comment: What is the mapping of the `backend_processing_time` field?

Comment: @AndreiStefan I have edited my question with the mapping of `backend_processing_time` field. I think that dynamic mapping created during grok parsing in logstash might be causing this.

Comment: Well, there could be many reasons for that field to be automatically mapped as string: in your LS you are not making sure the event content is actually a number and not a string. Also, it can happen that the template you have (if any) for those indices is ignoring that field as number and creates it as `string`. Or it can also happen that your first ever document that you send to ES for a new index will have an actual valid string in that field and thus creating the field with `text` as type.

Comment: @AndreiStefan So if I explicitly force this field to be a number in LS then it should solve my problem?

Comment: Yes, definitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take control of the mapping of those index(indices) so that your field will actually be a number. Otherwise, you will not be sure what kind of field type you'll have there. So, basically you need something like this, either in an index template, or a static mapping all the way:

```
    "backend_processing_time": {
      "type": "integer"
    }
```

Comment: This should work. I will try it and then accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove space in your query_string. i.e Your query_string should look like this:

```
backend_processing_time:>0.5
```

Read more about query_string syntax [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_ranges)

Comment: I tried doing this but still seeing the same result. I am editing my question to get this out of the way.

Comment: @shivams Can you provide an example doc?

Comment: So by example doc, if i provide json object of the 1 result is it okey?

Comment: When i again see the result that i just pasted, in the highlight section it is showing `backend_processing_time.keyword`. Should i assume that elasticsearch is treating backend_processing_time as keyword type and not number. Although in the left side column of kibana this field is shown as number type.